# trying to find the correct regular expression

Tags: regex

I have the following cases that should match with a regular expression, I've tried several combinations and have read a lot of answers but still no clue on how to solve it.

the rule is, find any  combination of . inside a quoted string, atm I have the following regexp

\"\w*((..)|(.))\w*\"

that covers most of the cases:

mmmas"A.F"asdaAA

196.34.45.."asd."@

".add"

sss"a.aa"sss

".."

"a.."

"a..a"

"..A"

but still having problems with this one:
"WERA.HJJ..J"

I've been testing the regpexp in the http://regexr.com/ site

I will really appreciate any help on this

Comment: Please properly format your question. What language/tool do you want to apply your regex to? What do you want to do with the dots after capturing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex to

```
\"\w*(\.+\w*)+\"
```

Update: escape . to match the dot and not any character

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/GrT5Mn/2)

Comment: This would match `"abc"` as well. @ICM you want to match only the ones with dots right?

Comment: @SimonPA Still it matches "abc" since the pattern before the closing quotes is set as optional.

Comment: I think that the last version  is wokring correctly,   \"\w*(\.+\w*)+\"  this one doesnt match "acb" but is matching the rest... nice, thank you guys

Comment: hi again, now that I tested the regexp I need to include it on my java editor but I'm getting the invalid scape sequence, I tried to scape the  backslashes but still getting errors on my regepx, did I need to add anything else?   \\"\\w*(\\.+\\w*)+\\"

Comment: oh , i found it... 3slashes... \\\"\\w*(\\.+\\w*)+\\\"

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it seems that you need to find every occurrence of one or more dot (along with optional word characters) inside a pair of quotes. The following regex would do this:

```
\"\w*(\.+\w*)+\"
```

In `"WERA.HJJ..J"`, you have some word characters followed by a dot which is followed by a sequence of word characters again followed by dot and word characters. Your regex would match `one or two dots with a pair of optional word character blocks on either sides` only.

The dots in the regex are escaped to avoid them being matched against any character, since it is a metacharacter.

Check [here](http://regexr.com/3eh44).